# Prototype swallows javascript errors (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, prototypejs

Hey i'm pretty new to prototype.
The problem is that javascript errors within dom:loaded callback functions don't get displayed in firefox (webconsole/errorconsole/firebug). 
Sample1:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
syntax() error()
});
```

Sample2:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
syntax(); error()
});
```

Now the funny thing: 
If I execute Sample1 I get an javascript error "Missing ; before statement" - ofcourse there should be a semicolon before 'error()' - so this type of error seems to work. If I execute Sample2 I don't get any error (actually it's not a syntax error anymore) but I should get a "undefined variable" error which i don't get.
Any clue what's going on here? 
IE prints out the error btw

Comment: You could try putting `"use strict";` at the top of the Javascript file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

what's happening is that in sample 2 when the semicolon is added the string `syntax; error` acts as two individual global variables, to the compiler it looks the same as `window.syntax; window.error`

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    syntax = 10; error = 5;
    alert(syntax + ' ' + error);
});
```

Try running the above example. it will help explain the issue more clearly...

Comment: Ok maybe my sample wasn't that good but I get the same result if I try it with syntax(); error(); which should give me an error that the functions are undefined